# C++ Eclipse not cooperating with classes

Tags: c++

I've been trying to get into a more object-oriented programming with C++, and I don't see what I'm doing wrong, as eclipse is giving me an error no matter what.

okay, the class is called steak, as this is not a real program, just an experiment.
Here is steak.cpp

```
#include "Steak.h"
Steak::Steak()
{

}

void Steak::cook()
{

}
```

and steak.h

```
#ifndef STEAK_H_
#define STEAK_H_

class Steak
{
    public:
        Steak();
        void cook();

};

#endif
```

It has errors on (in Steak.cpp) Steak::Steak(), Steak::cook() (which is just trying to see if I can make a function)

'Steak' has not been declared
'Steak' is not a class or namespace

Thanks for the responses, but it still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: You're doing this totally wrong: `#include "Steak.cpp"` Most probably you'll need some forward declaration elsewhere.

Comment: Well, The issue still isn't fixed despite this edit.

Comment: That's not the way you're supposed to improve your post. Provide a clear and reproducible sample, along with the verbatim error messages you get.

Comment: I did. They were already there.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a duplicate as far as I can see.  The OP made the changes around includes and it still doesn't work so it's not the same problem as in the linked issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include steak.h into steak.cpp, you are doing it the other way around. First declare the prototype in the header file, then include the header file into the cpp.

Comment: I already had it like that, but forgot to include it, accidentally omitted it in the copy/paste- I also removed the #include "steak.cpp"

Comment: use `#include "steak.h"` instead of `#include "Steak.h"` if your system is case-sensitive (like most Unix-like). And btw you need a `int main()` function as the starting point of the program.

Comment: Good point. Though this should come along with a simple `include file not found` error message. I simply believe the OP is cheating us with the code, and the error messages they're showing.

Comment: But the class is called Steak, not steak, and yes, I have a main, I just don't show it b/c it is not part of the problem.

Comment: it doesn't matter how the class is called, it matters how the header is called, that is what you include. Your `Steak` class can for example be declared into a file called `Potato.h`. In C++ the header file does not have to have the same name as the name of the class (unlike Java)

Comment: The header is the same case

Comment: I fixed it. I don't know how, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your cpp file needs to include the header, not the other way around

Comment: I forgot to include that, but I had it. the problem still persists.